# what is the difference between python shell and IDLE?

Tags: python

As python has two ways to code one from python command and one from python shell what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python Shell is a command line tool that starts up the python interpreter. You can test simple programs and also write some short programs. However, in order to write a more complexed python program you need an editor. IDLE, on the other hand, has combined the above two needs and bundled them as a package. IDLE consists of Python Shell, and Text editor that supports highlights for python grammar and etc.